# How to make on the fly duplicate values validation more efficient using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, performance

I have a performance question for a React app.
I implementing a "table editing page", the users need to be able to add multiple rows and columns and then set names to them and also have indicators next to the inputs whether these names are empty or not unique.
The table structure when returned from backend is this

```
{
  name: "table name",
  columns: [
    {
      name: "column1",
      token: "column1token"
    }
  ],
  rows: {
    ROWNAME1: {
      column1token: "value in ROWNAME1"
    }
 }
```

}

I have a preprocessing function which modifies the structure of the `rows` object in the table to be similar to `columns` to be kept in the state of the component:

```
 {
      name: "table name",
      columns: [
        {
          name: "column1",
          token: "column1token"
        }
      ],
      rows: [
        {
           name: "ROWNAME1",
           token: "newtoken",
           values: {
             column1token: "value in ROWNAME1"
          }
     ]
   }
```

Every time user adds a new row/column, it gets inserted into the appropriate array with randomly generated `token` and an empty `name`. When changing the name I check in the arrays if it is duplicate or not.
For smaller tables this works fine, but for a table with 300+ rows it becomes slow.

Is there a better approach to solving this task? Can using `Map` be more efficient than iterating over arrays?

Comment: Well where's the function? How can anybody help if we can't see it?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Map` would definitely be faster than working with arrays. But something here doesn't fit... even with 1,000 items search, Javascript should do it very fast. I would think that you might have a BIG react redraw, instead of small update to the DOM.

Are you using the `key` property for each row in the table?